# changes not updating in ImageJ

Tags: image-processing, imagej

guys just now i downloaded the ImageJ Jar. Completely new to it. I tried flipping/rotating the image. The program is executing but no changes are being reflected to the image. 
My code is ---

```
    import ij.ImagePlus;
    import ij.process.ImageProcessor;

    public class ImageProcessing{
    public static void main(String arg[]){
    ImagePlus imp= new ImagePlus("images/Koala.jpg");
    ImageProcessor ip=imp.getProcessor();
    try{ip.rotateLeft();}catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    imp.updateAndDraw();

}
}
```

Stuck since an hour, kindly help guys...
thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ImageProcessor#rotateLeft()`](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/process/ImageProcessor.html#rotateLeft%28%29) returns a new `ImageProcessor`, that should be assigned to the `ImagePlus`again.

The following code works for me within [Fiji/ImageJ](http://fiji.sc/Script_Editor):

```
import ij.IJ;
import ij.ImagePlus;
import ij.plugin.PlugIn;
import ij.process.ImageProcessor;

public class Image_Processing implements PlugIn {
    public void run(String arg){
        ImagePlus imp = IJ.openImage("http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/images/clown.jpg");
        ImageProcessor ip=imp.getProcessor().rotateLeft();
        imp.setProcessor(ip);
        imp.show();
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but is there any way to update the source image ?

Comment: i created a new Image and saved it to the hardisk ! anyway thank you sir